# Frequency of reading a GPIO in RASPBERRY PI3

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, frequency, gpio

How fast can my raspberry read my GPIO? For example, if I send him 300Mb/s can he read it? Has anyone tested it?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I think you'd have a hard time reading / polling a GPIO pin at above 20 MHz / 20 MSPS. You'd need a real time kernel to make that happen as well. Raspbian would probably lock up at that polling rate.

Comment: Okay, because I saw in rasberry pi forum that a person was able to read his GPIO at 10 MHZ and I'm not sure about the maximum. Thanks for your response

Comment: I found https://plus.google.com/+HennerZeller/posts/X7hfPAJYFUB via Google

Comment: ooooo woooow !!! , this is interesting, it can read more than I thought but still not enough to read what I want, thank you so many guys for your response.

Answer (score 0):

We have bench marked two of the most popular python libraries, RPi.GPIO and PIGPIO, with regard to their performance in accurately reading interdependent high frequency input signals.

Both libraries perform well for frequencies of up to 5 KHz with an accuracy above 99%. The accuracy of the Rpi.GPIO library deteriorates over 5 KHz and at 50 KHz it is incapable of performing this task.

The PIGPIO library performs comparably better, with its accuracy being above 99% for frequencies up to 20 KHz. Above that frequency, its performance gradually deteriorates and at 110 KHz it cannot read correctly any phrase at all.

You can read more about our test [here](https://atman-iot.com/blog/raspberry-pi-benchmark/).

Comment: What about bare metal?